# Why are "double braces" needed in declaration of multi-dimensional array using stacked std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdarray

```
#include <array>
using std::array;

constexpr auto d1=2;
constexpr auto d2=3;
constexpr auto d3=4;

// stacked std::array
using arr_t   = array<int,d1>;
using arr2d_t = array<arr_t,d2>;
using arr3d_t = array<arr2d_t,d3>;
constexpr arr3d_t arr1 = {{
    {{  {1,2},  {3,4},  {5,6}  }},
    {{  {1,2},  {3,4},  {5,6}  }},
    {{  {1,2},  {3,4},  {5,6}  }},
    {{  {1,2},  {3,4},  {5,6}  }}
}};

// built-in array
using carr3d_t = int[d3][d2][d1];
constexpr carr3d_t arr2 = {
    { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} },
    { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} },
    { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} },
    { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} }
};
```

Although, one can get away all the braces business with only pair of single braces like these:

```
// getaway with one-dimensional declaration
constexpr arr3d_t arr3 = {
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6,
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6,
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6,
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6
};
constexpr carr3d_t arr4 = {
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6,
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6,
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6,
    1,2,  3,4,  5,6
};
```

I'd like to know why `{{` are required except on the lowest dimension when using stacked std::array?

[godbolt.org/g/b6qfn4](https://gcc.godbolt.org/g/b6qfn4)

Answer (score 6):

The outer braces are [*aggregate initializer syntax*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and the inner are array initializer syntax.

C++14 allows **brace elision**. Make sure you are compiling with C++14 or better.

Answer (score 3):

Your types `arr_t`, `arr2d_t`, `arr3d_t` and `carr3d_t` are aggregate types. They are aggregate types because the [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) itself is an aggregate type. Their objects are initialized using [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and when compiling with the C++11 support you need the (extra) `{}` braces surrounding the nested initializer(s). Starting with the C++14 standard:

> the braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided (omitted)

Comment: I try both clang and gcc, it doesn't compile. This means they all don't opt c++14 brace elision for std::array case yet? [godbolt.org/g/YWAbHo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/g/YWAbHo)